# Build HDFView 3.1 on ubuntu-20.04

Tags: hdf5, ubuntu-20.04

I have downloaded the deb file from the https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/HDF-JAVA/hdfview-3.1.2/bin/ link and install it via

```sh
sudo dpkg -i hdfview_3.1.2-1_amd64.deb
```

I didn't see any error during installation.
But `hdfview` didn't open.
I am using `java-1.11.0-openjdk` and `hdf5-1.10`.

How to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: The problem is GLIBC_2.32 is not in ubuntu 20.04 (it is in 20.10). Not sure how to solve it though as I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to solve this. The program gets installed in `/opt/hdfview`. However, starting it causes the error

```sh
$ ./bin/HDFView 
Error: dl failure on line 534
Error: failed /opt/hdfview/lib/runtime/lib/server/libjvm.so, because /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /opt/hdfview/lib/runtime/lib/server/libjvm.so)
Failed to launch JVM
```

We can fix this by patching the `libjvm.so` file:

1. Install java-15 if it is not present already:

```sh
sudo apt install openjdk-15-jre
```

2. Find the `libjvm.so` file:

```sh
cd /usr/lib
find . -name libjvm.so
```

In my case, the correct version is located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so`

3. Replace the `libjvm.so` in hdfview with a symlink to this `libjvm.so`

```sh
cd /opt/hdfview/lib/runtime/lib/server
sudo mv libjvm.so libjvm.so.bak
sudo ln -s  /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so libjvm.so
```

4. (optional) link the hdfview binary, so that it is found in the terminal

```sh
sudo ln -s /opt/hdfview/bin/HDFView /usr/local/bin/hdfview
```

Afterwards, you should be able to start `hdfview` both from the terminal and the icon.